# How to count the elements in XML using XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have an XML message based on the w3schools lessons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8""?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

And I have this XPath script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp;
}

var x=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
var xml=x.responseXML;
path="/bookstore/book/price";

{
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result=nodes.iterateNext();

while (result)
  {
  document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  result=nodes.iterateNext();
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As of now, the code correctly displays a list of prices, that's exactly what I want to have. But then I want to display at the end the number of instances that were found; in out case should return just 4.
I tried adding:

```
document.write("<br>");
document.write(count(//price));
```

, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure where I go wrong. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Two things, try using nodes.length. And try not to use w3schools as reference, it's unreliable

Comment: My bad on the first point, use count(//book/price), but the second point is valid. Don't use w3schools

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and it doesn't work, the output is blank, so there must be an error. if I put this into a var and declare it, I then get an output, but it says undefined

Comment: OK, it's document.evaluate(“count(//book/price)“, document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).getNumberValue(); [http://js-xpath.sourceforge.net/xpath-example.html] Search for count on the page. It's in the final example

Comment: Still doesn't work, it's very weird and I think there's something wrong with the count method because the same syntax you gave me works for the other part

Comment: I think I know what's wrong, don't use document in the evaluate parameter, use x, the XML document variable document.evaluate(“count(//book/price)“, x, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).getNumberValue(), if it doesn't work use the xml var: document.evaluate(“count(//book/price)“, xml, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).getNumberValue()

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond to this, unfortunately it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
while (result)
{
  document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  result=nodes.iterateNext();
}
document.write(nodes.length);
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and it doesn't work, the output is blank, so there must be an error. if I put this into a var and declare it, I then get an output, but it says undefined